# Make [objc-bridging-header] a synonym of [bridging-header]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

These tags are not popular, so I do see a need to make awareness of my synonym request. (Also, I *really* need that badge.)

[bridging-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bridging-header) **- 160 questions**

[objc-bridging-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objc-bridging-header) **- 25 questions**

These two more or less mean the same.

Comment: You could just go ahead and edit the 25 to swap the tag. The [objc-bridging-header] tag will then disappear within a day or so.

Comment: @Josh Yes, but…why? A moderator can merge the tags and create a synonym in a single step, no disruptive and tedious editing required. The only reason I don't implement these right away is I can't always personally vouch for their correctness, so I need to wait for some type of community consensus to be established.